# pixel encoding using PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a naive question, but after a long day, I am not still able to get my answer.
I am currently loading my png image using PIL, it works well. However, some of my png 
images are 16-bit per pixel. I am trying desperately to query this information, but I am not able to get it, using PIL. Indeed, if I am simply using the `file` system binary it works.

```
$ file flower_16b.png 
flower_16b.png: PNG image data, 660 x 600, 16-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
```

However in my python code:

```
img = Image.open(filename, "r")
print(img.mode)
```

I get `RGB`. Following the documentation [PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#modes) RGB means (3x8-bit pixels, true color), it look likes the image has been casted. So does it exist a way to get the depth of an image, using PIL or an other python module ?

Comment: AFAIK the only 16-bit [PNG pixel format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Pixel_format) is grayscale, so claiming you're getting RGB doesn't make sense. You also haven't said _why_ you need the depth information…

Comment: @martineau I think OP means *"Truecolor"* which is 3 channels of 16-bits each, i.e. the `48` in your linked table.

Comment: I am running inference problem. My research team certifies it is only work with 8 bit-pixel png, but as you said it is a non sense, as the standard color is 8-bit pixel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PIL/Pillow doesn't [support](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes) 48-bit images like that. One option might be **OpenCV** but be aware it comes as BGR not RGB:

```
import cv2

# Read with whatever bit depth is specified in the image file
BGR = cv2.imread('image.png', cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH|cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)

# Check dtype and number of channels
print(BGR.dtype, BGR.shape)

dtype('uint16'), (768, 1024, 3)
```

---

Another option may be `pyvips`, which works a slightly different way, but has some good benefits:

```
import pyvips

im = pyvips.Image.new_from_file('image.png', access="sequential")

print(im)
<pyvips.Image 1024x768 ushort, 3 bands, rgb16>
```

---

If you are really, really stuck and can't/won't install **OpenCV** or **pyvips**, you have a couple more options with **ImageMagick**...

You could reduce your 3 RGB channels (16-bits each) to 3 RGB channels (8-bits each) with:

```
magick input.png PNG24:output.png      # then open "output.png" with PIL
```

Or, you could separate the 3 RGB channels into 3 separate 16-bit files and process them separately with **PIL/Pillow**:

```
magick input.png -separate channel-%d.png
```

and you will get the red channel as a 16-bit image in `channel-0.png` which you can open with **PIL/Pillow**, the green as `channel-1.png` and the blue as `channel-2.png`

Comment: To convert BGR into RGB, simply do `RGB = BGR[..., ::-1]`

Comment: @Mark Thank you very much for all your proposition !